# trouble with nginx and django gunicorn socks setup

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, supervisord

So I followed this tutorial (http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/) and everything went smoothly till the end when I erase the default config for mine in sites-available and sites-enabled the restart nginx. When I navigate to my site I get a "site cant be reached" error. I created the link for new config to sites-enabled from sites-available. supervisorctl says its running my gunicorn start script when I check the status. What I notice though is that at no point is gunicorn.sock created in the run directory. Am I supposed to create that? I tried that but to no avail. Can someone help

Comment: `gunicorn.sock` is use as socket connection and program should create it. Check nginx na gunicorn logs - they can be in `/var/log/`

Comment: you're right this is what I got: 

  File "/home/devin/webuildblack/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named 'wsgi-app'
[2016-10-30 15:16:17 +0000] [1928] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 1928)
[2016-10-30 15:16:17 +0000] [1925] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2016-10-30 15:16:17 +0000] [1925] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.

Comment: you have somewhere `wsgi-app` and probably should be `wsgi_app` but I'm not sure.